# inline термин в контексте C# / JIT компилятора

Tags: c#, методы, компилятор, inline, jit

Добрый день.
Столкнулся с таким вопросом,а именно хочу четко понять определение термина,такого как **inline** метод, соответственно в контексте C#(чтобы вопросы такого рода как "заинлайнить метод" отпали).

И вторая часть вопроса,почему **JIT** компилятору предпочтительнее inline методы?

Comment: если ты не знаешь определение термина _inline метод_, как ты можешь говорить, что _JIT компилятору предпочтительнее inline методы_?

Comment: @Grundy наверное потому что сталкивался с литературой\статьями,где пишут такое? Странный вопрос.

Comment: Ну так в той литературе и определение термина должно быть.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В контексте C#, насколько я понимаю, `inline`-подстановка означает оптимизацию при компиляции, при которой тело вызываемого метода встраивается в вызывающую функцию вместо вызова. На текущий момент такими оптимизациями занимается только JIT-компилятор.

В C# вы не можете *заставить* компилятор *заинлайнить* функцию, но вы можете попросить его об этом, используя атрибут `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]`. Также вы можете попросить компилятор не встраивать функцию, указав атрибут `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]`.

---

В отличие от этого в C++ ключевое слово `inline` означает, что сборщик должен игнорировать факт множественного определения функции в различных модулях компиляции (ослабляя тем самым ODR).

---

По поводу второй части вопроса: инлайнингом в C# занимается JIT-компилятор потому, что он знает точно целевую платформу. Точные критерии решения JIT-компилятора насчёт того, инлайнить ли данную функцию, меняются от версии к версии.

Согласно [этому сообщению](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/01/20/aggressive-inlining-in-the-clr-45-jit/), инлайнингу *не подвержены* методы, которые:

- Маркированы атрибутом `MethodImplOptions.NoInlining`
- Размер IL-кода которых больше 32 байт (при отсутствии атрибута `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining`)
- Виртуальные методы
- Метод, принимающие тип-значение большого размера как параметр
- Методы в классах, производных от `MarshalByRefObject`
- Методы со сложным потоком управления

  - например, рекурсивные методы
  - и методы с обработкой исключений
- Методы с экзотическими инструкциями, проверками безопасности и т. п.

Вот такой «список предпочтений» JIT-компилятора насчёт инлайн-методов.

Этот список, разумеется, не финальный, и будет пересматриваться (в сторону ослабления) в последующих версиях.

Comment: _"оптимизацию при компиляции"_ - при какой именно?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Дописал в ответ: при JIT.

Comment: @VladD, а где ответ на _вторую часть_? :)

Comment: @VladD спасибо,теперь понятнее !

Comment: _"Метод, принимающие тип-значение большого размера как параметр"_ - логичнее было бы наоборот? Да и 32 байта il-кода - это как-то мало...

Comment: @Grundy: Написал :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, большинство методов передают маленькие параметры, `int` или там `double`.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Угу, хозяин, 32 байта, я сама офигела!

Comment: @Qwertiy 32х байт достаточно для коротких функций-оберток, вроде `T Resolve<T>() => (T)Resolve(typeof(T))`.